# Access to gnuplot variables

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

Is it possible to access gnuplot variables from LaTeX without writing to a external file?

The only way I know is to write to a file from gnuplot and read it again from LaTeX. It is however cumbersome and require you to keep track of filenames and the order of variables. Is there a better way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
  X Y
  1.000 0.00
  2.000 2.00
  3.000 6
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[only marks] table {data.csv};
    \addlegendentry{Data}

    \addplot+[raw gnuplot, no markers] gnuplot {
      stats 'data.csv'; % Calculate a bunch of statistical values
      plot [x=0:5] STATS_slope*x + STATS_intercept; % plot the linear fit
      set print "parameters.dat"; % Open a file to save the parameters into
      print STATS_slope; % Write the parameters to file
      print STATS_intercept;
      print STATS_correlation;x
    };

    \newread\myread % Open the file again
    \openin\myread=parameters.dat
    \read\myread to \mytmp \pgfmathprintnumberto{\mytmp}{\slope} % Read the values from the file and pprint them to macros
    \read\myread to \mytmp \pgfmathprintnumberto{\mytmp}{\intercept}
    \read\myread to \mytmp \pgfmathpow{\mytmp}{2} \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=5]{\pgfmathresult}{\Rsq} % Square the r value before pprinting
    \addlegendentry{$y=\slope \cdot x + \intercept$, ${R}^{2}=\Rsq$}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: all input to tex is via files (or standard in) depending on what you want to pass it might be simpler to print tex syntax from gnuplot and then simply `\input` the file rather than read it line by line with `\read`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a command that keeps track of the files. It stil writes the variables to an external file, but it makes it much easier to use as you don't need to keep track of filenames. I hope that can help others to add a fast linear regression to a plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\newcommand{\linregAddplot}[2][]{%
  % Will plot a linear regression from a datafile.
  %
  % Usage: \linregAddplot[<options>]{<file>}
  % where <options> is the same options as for \addplot+ and <file> is a simple
  % datafile gnuplot can read.
  %
  % The macros \linregSlope, \linregIntercept and \linregRsq are available after
  % \linregAddplot has been called. They can be used in
  % \addlegendentry{}.

    \addplot+[raw gnuplot, no markers, #1] gnuplot {
    stats '#2' nooutput; % Calculate a bunch of statistical values
    plot [x=STATS_min_x:STATS_max_x] STATS_slope*x + STATS_intercept;
    set print "#2.linreg";
    print STATS_slope; % Write the parameters to file
    print STATS_intercept;
    print STATS_correlation;
  };
  \IfFileExists{./#2.linreg}{
    \expandafter\newread\csname read#2\endcsname % Open the file again
    \expandafter\openin\csname read#2\endcsname=#2.linreg

    % Read the values from the file
    \expandafter\read\csname read#2\endcsname to \mytmp
    % and pprint them to tmp macros
    \pgfmathprintnumberto{\mytmp}{\linregSlope}

    \expandafter\read\csname read#2\endcsname to \mytmp
    \pgfmathprintnumberto{\mytmp}{\linregIntercept}

    \expandafter\read\csname read#2\endcsname to \mytmp
    % Square the r value before pprinting
    \pgfmathpow{\mytmp}{2}
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=5]{\pgfmathresult}{\linregRsq}
      }{%
    \def\linregSlope{NaN}
    \def\linregIntercept{NaN}
    \def\linregRsq{NaN}
    \message{You need to run LaTeX again to get you linear regression labels right.}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
  X Y
  1.000 0.00
  -2.000 2.00
  3.000 14
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
  X Y
  -1.000 0.00
  -2.000 2.00
  3.000 -3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[only marks] table {data.csv};
    \addlegendentry{Data}

    \linregAddplot{data.csv}
    \addlegendentry{$y=\linregSlope \cdot x + \linregIntercept$, ${R}^{2}=\linregRsq$}

    \addplot[only marks] table {data2.csv};
    \addlegendentry{Data2}

    \linregAddplot[dashed]{data2.csv}
    \addlegendentry{$y=\linregSlope \cdot x + \linregIntercept$, ${R}^{2}=\linregRsq$}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```